# How to install .net 5 sdk in mac m1

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, sdk

Not being able to install .net 5 sdk in my mac m1. I am trying to compile a c# project and its asking for .net 5.0 sdk.

i tried downloading it from the official website but arm64 was not present in it. Do it need to install Rosetta 2 in my mac for it.

Comment: .NET 5 is out of support. You may want to update to at least .NET 6

Comment: .NET 5 was released in 2020 in November, the same month that Apple ARM M1 was released.  Zero months is probably not enough time to implement support for .NET 5 on Mac M1.

Comment: @Eljay to be fair, the latest .NET 5 release is May 10, 2022 - however: adding an entire new OS/architecture entry is outside the usual service patch cycle

Answer (score 1):

.NET 5 is out of support; you probably don't actually want/need this

.NET 6 has ARM64 for macOS baked in (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0), but you may prefer to just jump to "current": https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/ (.NET 8 at time of writing, i.e. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/8.0)